# Is there still uncharted land?

Tags: factoids, where-on-earth, extreme-tourism

Recently I drove on a road not yet mapped on [osm](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/51.500/-0.100). As soon as I get back, I will add it. It made me wonder if every piece of land is already mapped, or if you could still have a bit of adventure, doing some real exploring.

Comment: Related question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3197/324